# What closed-cockpit biplane is this model modelled after?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

What closed-cockpit biplane is this model modelled after?

[image]

Comment: If you took the photographs yourself, please add (own work) under the photo, otherwise state the source/URL please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Beechcraft_D17S_Staggerwing_CF-GKY_01.JPG))

[Beechcraft Model 17 Staggerwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Model_17_Staggerwing) first flew in 1932. It flew air races, served in WW2, and served as a civilian transport. One of its rare features is the lower wing being ahead of the top wing.

> The Model 17's unusual negative stagger wing configuration (the upper wing staggered behind the lower) and unique shape maximized pilot visibility while negligibly reducing interference between the wings.