# What floatplane is this model?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What floatplane is this model?

[image]
[image]
[image]

(own work)

Comment: The pedant in me feels the need to mention that N679 is not a floatplane. Depending on period it is either a Standard J-1 or an Aerospace Quail. There are 52 current N-numbers for the G-44 not including the A model http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Mms_Results.aspx?Mmstxt=3951502&conVal=0&PageNo=1

Comment: @JuanCarlosVelasco, you have several questions like this, where you show views of a 3D model you say is your own work. If it is something you have done you must know the answer already, in which case you are using this site to showcase your own work. If you truly do not know the model then this cannot be your own work. I think it would be good for you to clarify the basis of your question.

Comment: @GdD I assume he means the photography is his own work.

Comment: @fooot still there's a possibility the upload on SE is the work.

Comment: @qqjkztd he seems to have started adding it [after being asked to cite the images.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48936/what-closed-cockpit-biplane-is-this-model-modelled-after#comment127957_48936)

Comment: @GdD I being asked to cite the images as my own work

Comment: @GdD I have a collection of approximately 1,200 airplane models, none of them have been assembled by me. I'm trying to identify the name of each of them. I have been able to identify the majority through books and aviation websites. Only when I can not identify an airplane I ask in the forum. All the photos that I upload are taken by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [Grumann G-44 Widgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_G-44_Widgeon).

[image: G-44 Widgeon]
([source](http://www.john2031.com/grumman/widgeon/pictures-1/photos_1.html))